# Windows 10, shortcut to snap windows with multiple monitors (win+arrows)

Tags: multiple-monitors, windows-10-preview, aero-snap

I am used to press `WIN`+arrow to snap window to the side of a monitor. If I press it more times, the windows cycles through monitors.

E.g. I have to monitors. If I have some window at the arbitrary position at the right monitor and press `WIN`+`left`, windows snaps to the left side of the right monitor. If I press it once more, window snaps to the right side of the left monitor, than left side of the left monitor ...

BUT This is not working in windows 10. Build 9841
It snaps only within one monitor.

Does anybody know a way to restore original behavior?

Comment: Sounds like a bug or an unfinished feature in the 10 preview, you should report it via the provided Feedback App in the Preview. See: http://www.howtogeek.com/197604/how-to-send-feedback-to-microsoft-in-the-windows-10-technical-preview/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about bugs in beta/preview software. (See: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/8588/are-windows-10-preview-questions-on-topic)